# If I enter the USA with dual US/Caribbean Island citizenship and only present my Caribbean passport will they know I am a USA citizen?

Tags: legal, customs-and-immigration, international-travel, us-citizens, dual-nationality

I have dual citizenship, USA & a Caribbean island. If I enter the USA with only my Caribbean island passport, will they know I am a USA citizen?

Comment: It is a good way to spend more time with the customs :)

Comment: Not quite an answer but wouldn't you be asked for a visa with your other passport? Also, airlines transmit data on their passengers to US authorities. I don't know how these data are used but if you presented your US passport to the airline, it could be a way for CBP to notice you. Finally, as an alien, you would typically be asked about the purpose of the trip, etc. You might have to lie or reveal information that betrays your citizenship or at least raises suspicion.

Answer (score 6):

As a US citizen, you *must* enter the USA under your American passport, not using any other, it's illegal to do otherwise.

> **I am an American citizen, but also have a foreign passport. Can I use my foreign passport to travel to the United States?**
>
> No. Under U.S. law, U.S. citizens must be in possession of a valid U.S. passport to enter or leave the United States. This is true even if you hold a passport from another country. If your U.S. passport has been lost or stolen, or if it has expired, you must apply to replace it before traveling to the United States.

[Source](https://uk.usembassy.gov/u-s-citizen-services/u-s-passports/u-s-passport-faqs/u-s-citizenship/#collapse3) (US embassy in the UK)

> **U.S. nationals, including dual nationals, must use a U.S. passport to enter and leave the United States.**

[Source](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/legal/travel-legal-considerations/Advice-about-Possible-Loss-of-US-Nationality-Dual-Nationality/Dual-Nationality.html) (State Department)

As for if they would know, that depends (there are ways that suggest it, including but not only place of birth, along with some databases), but [Travel.SE policy is not to aid people in breaking the law](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1405/how-should-questions-answers-on-how-to-do-something-illegal-be-treated) so alas all we can say is you need to enter on your US passport...

Comment: That's not the question, though... will they know the OP is a US citizen?

Comment: (Although I think it's worth pointing out the legal issue, but the question should still be answered. The fact that they are asking the question probably implies they already understand the legal implications).

Comment: @Flimzy, frankly, I'm less confident regarding the understanding of the law. I don't understand it myself (had never even heard of it despite living here 30 years and leaving the country >4 times), but I'd bet the implication *of* the law is that, without your passport, how *can* customs know? Hopefully, they actually do have other means that someone else will speak to – e.g., checking citizenship records somewhere – but to me the law suggests they don't want the hassle and prefer to turn people away rather than make them wait for a lengthier process that involves more work on their end...

Comment: @Flimzy [Standing policy is not to help people trying to act illegally](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1405/how-should-questions-answers-on-how-to-do-something-illegal-be-treated)

Comment: @Gagravarr: 1) The policy you quote is not nearly that hard-lined. 2) It's not necessary that the OP is *trying* to do something illegal. 3) There are times on this site when advice to do something possibly "illegal" has [stood](http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/26231/444)--in fact in a situation nearly identical to this one.

Comment: @Flimzy If the OP enters the US on their non-US passport, then they will be breaking US law whether they get caught or not

Comment: @Gagravarr: So as not to get hung up on the technicality, pretend the question is "I know it's illegal, but out of curiosity, would they know?"

Comment: (Or ask the OP for clarification as to why they want this information... maybe they are indeed trying to break the law, in which case I think your answer is fine. Maybe they weren't aware of the law, in which case perhaps your answer is fine, as well)

Comment: Depends. I know at least one person (wife of a good friend) who was identified as a US citizen at immigration despite travelling on their European passport, so it can happen

Comment: There's also the fact that if you present a non-US passport, there's a risk that even if they don't spot you're a US citizen they might deny you entry!

Comment: @NickStauner - your passport *is* your record of citizenship.

Comment: @Gagravarr what happened to your friend's wife when she was caught at the border?

Comment: @phoog Got a massive telling off, notes were taken, and was informed that if she tried it again she'd receive a fine

Comment: @Gagravarr hmm, I wonder. The part of the law that specified a punishment for violating the requirement to enter with a US passport was repealed nearly 40 years ago.  I am curious how a fine would be imposed, that is, under what authority.  (I have my suspicions, but so far I have never heard of anyone being fined.)

Comment: The source link is a 404. A cite to the actual USC or CFR would be more useful.